# Retrieve specific date between crossed dates SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have table for dates and when the user enters a date, I want to get single record with the right value range. The problem is that date ranges intersect.

These are the table data I have

> Record 1 | Sartdate 2019/01/01 | Enddate 2019/12/31
>
> Record 2 | Sartdate 2019/12/01 | Enddate 2019/12/31

For example when I enter `2019-05-1` I should get record 1 and when I enter `2019-12-05` I should get record 2. When I enter `219-12-05` I get 2 records which is wrong.

I created a SQL statement but I get the wrong value each time  and I don't how to fix it

```
declare @currentrow int = 0

set @dateQuery = '2018-04-01'

select @count = count(*) from [dbo].[t_dates]

while @currentrow <  @count  
begin
    select @dateFrom = [date_from], @dateTo = [date_to]
    from [t_dates] 
    where date_id = @currentrow + 1

    select @dateId = date_id 
    from [dbo].[t_dates] 
    where ((@dateQuery between @dateFrom and @dateTo))

    print @dateId
    print @dateFrom
    print @dateTo

    set @currentrow = @currentrow + 1
end
```

Comment: You don't want or need a loop here. Are you just trying to get a list of incremental dates between two dates?

Comment: Not enough explanation.   What is the "wrong value"?  what is the "right value"?   What does this code have to do with your "table data"?

Comment: For example when I enter 2019-05-1 I should get record 1 and when I enter 2019-12-05 I should get record 2. When I enter 219-12-05 I get 2 records which is wrong

Comment: But why are you doing this in a loop???

Comment: *when I enter 2019-05-1 I should get record 1* why would you get this record? This value doesn't fall in the range at all.

Comment: You might want to take a peek at this also. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Comment: @TabAlleman This is actually a decent question

Comment: @T.S.  Sorry, even after your edit, I still find the question completely unclear.   I see the poster has accepted an answer, so unless someone can edit the question to make it useful to future readers, my vote is to leave it closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT top 1 [date_from],[date_to]
FROM [t_dates] 
WHERE @dateQuery between [date_from] AND [date_to]
ORDER BY [date_to] desc,[date_from] desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all of the variables. A simple where clause should suffice.

```
SELECT *
FROM [t_dates]
WHERE Sartdate <= @dateQuery and EndDate >= @dateQuery
```

This will return records where your `@dateQuery` falls into the *range* between the `Sartdate` and `EndDate`. I also assume `Sartdate` is a typo in your post, but I kept it here for clarity.

Comment: Why did you vote to close it, its a valid question?

Comment: Was before an edit

Comment: So you should nominate it for re-open. be fair

Comment: I didn’t know it got closed. Why are you saying I am not fair? That’s quite insulting

Comment: what do you mean? - you voted to close this question. But it is decent question. You also posted an answer and earned 10 points. Why do vote to close it if you answered it? May be I have my version of the answer and I want to post it.

Comment: I would say that currently this still isn't a great question. The sample data is a hot mess and the explanation in the question is almost non-existent. The clarity came from people attempting to answer it. And the OP has already selected an answer as the solution.

Comment: @SeanLange I strongly disagree. I understood question immediately. I didn't look at the code but it was immediately clear that there are 2 date ranges with OP needs to select the range with latest start if the date falls under both. If questions like *"what is getdate() equivalent in MySql"* get no complaints - this is OK question... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246791/getdate-in-mysql

Comment: What’s stopping you from adding an answer? And my answer was a guess that still doesn’t fit the sample data. @SeanLange and I dont answer for internet points but if that’s your thing then ok. We just try and help folks and comment far more than we answer

Comment: When question is closed, no answer can be added by design of this site. whatever the mission is, all I ask is look and say, [in current edited format] is this an invalid question? There are far worse ones that live and well